# Nestjs extend/combine decorators?

Tags: node.js, typescript, decorator, nestjs

I have simple custom decorator:

```
export const User: () => ParameterDecorator = createParamDecorator(
  (data: any, req): UserIdentity => {
    const user = getUser(req);
    return user;
  },
);
```

And now, I need to validate if we have `email` in `user` object.

The problem is that I can't update my current decorator.

Could I extend my current decorator?

Create a new decorator based on the previous one or create a new decorator and combine it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can do ["decorator composition"](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition) with Nest, but this might not be a perfect solution for your case, depending on what you intend to do when `user` has no `email` property.

As per the example from the documentation:

```js
import { applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';

export function Auth(...roles: Role[]) {
  return applyDecorators(
    SetMetadata('roles', roles),
    UseGuards(AuthGuard, RolesGuard),
    ApiBearerAuth(),
    ApiUnauthorizedResponse({ description: 'Unauthorized"' }),
  );
}
```

*In this example, `Auth` is a decorator that can be used to combine all the one passed in `applyDecorators`.*

---

Thus, I'd recommend *extending* your decorator using [a pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#working-with-pipes).

As stated by the documentation:

> Nest treats custom param decorators in the same fashion as the built-in ones (@Body(), @Param() and @Query()). This means that pipes are executed for the custom annotated parameters as well (in our examples, the user argument). Moreover, you can apply the pipe directly to the custom decorator:

```js
@Get()
async findOne(@User(new ValidationPipe()) user: UserEntity) {
  console.log(user);
}
```

In this example, `User` is a custom parameter decorator. And `ValidationPipe` is passed, but you can imagine passing any [pipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes).

Comment: Thx for answer. Unfortunatelly I can't extend the current decorator right now (it's in another project and we use it as an npm package). I used applyDecorators and it works like a charm.