# Extend NestJS decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decorator, extends

I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094362/use-interceptor-inside-another-interceptor-in-nestjs) but I don't think I want to use an alias

I want to extend the express `anyFilesInterceptor` so I can work with a custom file object. I am not sure how to extend a decorator in NestJS.

So as a work around I tried decorator composition from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60692331/nestjs-extend-combine-decorators). However, I am getting an error just trying to create a very basic (example in documentation) decorator

```
import { applyDecorators, createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AnyFilesInterceptor } from "@nestjs/platform-express";

export function Test() {
  return applyDecorators(
    AnyFilesInterceptor,
    TestDecorator
  )
}

export const TestDecorator = createParamDecorator(
  (data: string, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;

    return data ? user?.[data] : user;
  },
);
```

Now I can see from other discussions and the function naming that `AnyFilesInterceptor` is a mixin that returns a class while `TestDecorator` created by `createParamDecorator` likely only works on parameters.

Does NestJS have a way to create a class decorator? Or to extend existing decorators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the `AnyFilesInterceptor` is a function itself that produces an interceptor (which is any class that implements `NestInterceptor`).
You can see it by the usage: while 'other' interceptors may be used by simply giving the class to the `UseInterceptor()` decorator, this interceptor needs invocation (without new keyword).
Example:

```js
@UseInterceptor(RegularInterceptor)
//or
@UseInterceptor(new RegularInterceptor())

// AnyFilesInterceptor is a function returning a class
@UseInterceptor(AnyFilesInterceptor())
//or
@UseInterceptor(new (AnyFilesInterceptor())({/* some multer options here */))
```

so basically if you want to extend the `AnyFilesInterceptor` you simply need to define a class inteceptor of your own:

```js
export class MyAllFilesInterceptor extends AnyFilesInterceptor() {
  // YOU MUST OVERRIDE THE `intercept` METHOD!
  // also, give options to the `AnyFilesInterceptor` method if you wish
}
```